# "Constants " in Haskell after start of the program

Tags: haskell, types, constants

I have a keyboard input like `unsafePerformIO $ entryGetText myTextEntry`. How can I save this value like a "constant" (in data Type like this:

```
data SimuInfo = Information {
                massSaved:: Double 
                } deriving Show
```

) after the program starts. The only method I know to "save variables" is:

```
valuea::Int
valuea = 120
```

But this method just works, when the value is not define by the user.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's wrong with `value = unsafePerformIO $ entryGetText myTextEntry`? (Aside from the fact that `unsafePerformIO` isn't supposed to depend on its environment.)

Comment: why are we using unsafePerformIO?

Comment: You're attempting to code impurely in a theoretically pure language. This will be an uphill battle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`unsafePerformIO` should be avoided at all costs](https://wiki.haskell.org/IO_inside#unsafePerformIO), as its execution is unpredictable.

Haskell is a pure language and values are immutable, so you won't be able to "save" a value that will show as mutated elsewhere.

Instead, you'll need to read the value in and pass it around as needed.

```haskell
main = do  
    putStrLn "Enter the default massSaved value"  
    val <- getLine
    doThingsWithDefaultSimuInfo (Information (read val :: Double))

doThingsWithDefaultSimuInfo :: SimuInfo -> IO ()
doThingsWithDefaultSimuInfo si = do
    ...
```

(There are cleaner and more idiomatic ways to do this with Readers but I'm trying to keep this answer aimed at beginner-level)

Comment: Just since it's been mentioned twice in answers, I wanted to mention that passing arguments to a function is a perfectly clean and idiomatic way to do this (IMHO `Reader` seldom pulls its weight as an abstraction)

Comment: You don't need the `:: Double` annotation on `read` here. Since its result is being passed to the `Information` constructor, the compiler knows the result must be `Double`.

Answer (score 0):

Values that are input from the user are not really constants.  I think the usual way to handle this kind of configuration input is with a reader Monad.

```
import Control.Monad.Reader

-- type of our context, one double value.
-- This is not really necessary, you could just use Double everywhere
-- I use C.
newtype C = C Double
  deriving (Show, Eq)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  -- Read a double from the user.
  c <- getLine >>= return . read :: IO Double
  -- Run the computation, given a context/configuration with
  -- the user input.
  print  $ runReader foo (C c)

-- Computation dependent on our context.
foo :: Reader C Double
foo = do
  C x <- ask -- Get the value of our context.
  return $ x + 10 --  and use it
```